# K8s RBAC serviceaccount with extended permissions

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I am looking for option to have serviceaccount  (which is not cluster admins) to be able to create new namespace and automatically get admin permission on it (while all system namespaces are not editable by this serviceaccount).

Currently my serviceaccount binded to clusterrole contains

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - create
```

However it can't do anything on namespace it creates.
Would like to get any suggestions, recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do using [RBAC objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) only.

> In the RBAC API, a role contains rules that represent a set of
>   permissions. Permissions are purely additive (there are no “deny”
>   rules).

However there is a possible workaround:

- you add a pod with Kubernetes python/go/java client inside, using service account with create-Roles+RoleBindings-permissions on a cluster level
- then you run a simple code that monitor api-server for new namespaces and create `RoleBinding` for the namespace-admin in the new namespace
- this `RoleBinding` refers to cluster-admin role, which gives the user all permission in the specific namespace
- to differentiate new namespaces from existing ones, the script can also put a label on the namespace: `namespace-admin=true` or similar.

Also, you could consider using RBAC Manager. [Dynamic Namespaces and Labels](https://github.com/FairwindsOps/rbac-manager#dynamic-namespaces-and-labels) to be more specific.

> RBAC Definitions can now include namespaceSelectors in place of
>   namespace attributes when specifying Role Binding configuration. This
>   can be incredibly helpful when working with dynamically provisioned
>   namespaces.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thank you, RBAC Manager seems like doing exactly what i looked for.